# Form Library Updating fields in Datasheet view cause error

Tags: infopath, datasheet

I have an InfoPath form that has been published and several fields have been promoted so that we can edit the fields in datasheet view. However, there are certain instances when we attempt to enter in a text value through the datasheet view that it gives us an error.

"Rows you changed were previously changed by "person" on "date".  Your changes conflict with that user's changes."

No matter what we do it gives us this error.

We had version control turned on, but have since turned it off to see if it would resolve the issue.  The only way to get around the issue is to open the form library in windows explorer, copy the form onto your desktop, delete the form from the sharepoint form library and then copy the version back into the windows explorer.  This is what leads me to believe it has something to do with the version, but I cannot confirm.